# jQuery Google Maps variable - pull in from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, input

I have a field which autosuggests places from Google Maps. As part of this code you can filter by country, with this bit of code:

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], {
  types: ["geocode"],
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: "uk"
  }
});
```

I want to try and pull in a variable using jQuery and then use this as my variable. I tried to use this code:

```
ctryiso = $("#ctry").val();
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], {
  types: ["geocode"],
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: "ctryiso"
  }
});
```

However it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here? I even tried this:

```
autocompleteOptions.componentRestrictions.country = ctryiso;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/5dqHg/10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the quotes around 'ctryiso':

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], {
  types: ["geocode"],
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: ctryiso
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but that didnt do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/5dqHg/16/

Comment: Check the id for the input. <input class="hidden" id="#ctry" disabled="true" value="us"></input> http://jsfiddle.net/5dqHg/19/